# Python Read Write Looping Traceback Errors

Tags: python

I get tracebacks such as below:

```
expected an indented block col += 1" and "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"
```

depending on how I play with this code. Can anyone see any obvious flaws/improvements? I'm trying to get some output results from a software program (Step 1), export output to `excel` with `openpyxl` (Step 2)

```
import Library
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename ='xxxxxx')
ws3 = wb.create_sheet('New results')

ws3['B1'] = 'Heading'   
ws3['B2'] = 'Heading'
ws3['C2'] = 'Heading'

ws3.cell(1, 3, 30)                                       
row = 3              

#Step 1: go through all files in directory and get required output from each file 

files=glob.glob('.ext')
for i,f in enumerate(files) : 
    m = Library.Model(f)
    frame = m['SoftwareModelComponent']
    TimeResult = frame.some call for resultxxxx
    DistResult = frame.some call for resultxxxx

#Step 2: send output to excel file located in same directory                                                    

for fileName in glob.glob('.ext'):
    col = 0
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                ws3.cell(i+row, 0, f)
                ws3.cell(i+row, 1+col, TimeResult)
                ws3.cell(i+row, 1+col, DistResult)
            except ValueError:
                print('Error') 
            col += 1
    row += 1            

wb.save('G:\\path')
wb.close('G:\\path')
```

Answer (score 0):

A "permission denied" error probably mean that you or your program don't have the right to write (or read) in a specific folder.
So, when you run the line :

```
wb.save('G:\\path')
```

vertify that this folder is open in writing.

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"Permission denied" errors appear when the file(s) you are working with in your code, is open or being used by another program/software. You should verify this by looking at the processes on your computer and find out which one(s) maybe using the files (with *.ext extension) and terminate them before running the program.

As for the indentation error, you should increment `col1` within the `try` block . This block takes control of the `for` loop execution above it. When you place `col1` outside of this block, you are violating the indentation rules in Python as `col1+=1` is outside the control flow of the `for` loop and has no significance:

```
try:
    ws3.cell(i+row, 0, f)
    ws3.cell(i+row, 1+col, TimeResult)
    ws3.cell(i+row, 1+col, DistResult)
    col +=1
```

Comment: I corrected the 'Col' indent. Restarted my machine. Checked the task manager. No files with applicable ext were running. Ran code again and got a permission error. The files are on a network. The only application that was open when I ran the code was the Spyder console itself

Comment: If the files are on a network, do you need administrative privileges to access them? You should isolate the problem and open just one file from the network with: `with open('path_to_file', 'r') as f: data = f.read() print(data)`. If you get the same error, then try running the script as admin. Also, can you show the full Traceback error for the "Permission denied" error?